# Disable Nagios recovery notification after WARNING?

Tags: nagios

Is there a way to disable recoveries from WARNING states (but keep the recovery messages from PROBLEM states?)

We only want to be notified when there is a PROBLEM with a service and when that service recovers.  What happens is that each time the service enters a WARNING state and then recovers we get that RECOVERY notification.  Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
notification_options        w,u,c
```

Comment: More information would be nice. Was there a mistake made in the editing process?

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a working solution.  This will not send notification on recoveries as I described we need.